# Counting points in a certain 4-dimensional region

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Let $(a,b,c)$ be a fixed tuple of co-prime integers, with $a \ne 0$ and at least one of $b,c$ non-zero. Define

$$L = -\frac{a p_1 q_1 - b p_2 q_1 - b p_1 q_2 + 4 c p_2q_2}{a},$$

$$Q = \frac{(b^2 - 4ac)(p_2 q_1 - p_1 q_2)^2}{4 a^2},$$
and
$$\displaystyle R = \frac{(a p_1^2 - 2bp_1p_2 + 4cp_2^2)(a q_1^2 - 2bq_1q_2 + 4cq_2^2)}{a^2}.$$

I want to count the number of $4$-tuples of integers $(p_1, p_2; q_1, q_2)$ such that

$$\displaystyle b p_1 - 2 c p_2 \equiv 0 \pmod{a}, b q_1 - 2 c q_2 \equiv 0 \pmod{a}$$

(this will in fact guarantee that $L,Q,R$ always take on integer values) and such that

$$\displaystyle L^2, |Q|, |R| \ll X.$$

Denote by $N(X)$ the number of points $(p_1, p_2; q_1, q_2)$ for which all of the above are satisfied. I am looking for a bound of the shape

$$\displaystyle N(X) = O_{a,b,c}(X).$$

Another result which I am also interested is whether the conditions imposed above imply any individual bounds for $p_1, p_2, q_1, q_2$ in terms of $X$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: it appears that when $f_{(a,b,c)} = ax^2 + bxy + cy^2$ is an irreducible indefinite quadratic form, then the number of solutions is infinite for any value of $X$, due to a non-trivial action arising from the unit group. Thus, we may assume that $f_{(a,b,c)}$ is either positive definite or reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.